# How to compact a dataset with empty rows in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set formatted as follows:

| sha | 0_x | 1_x | N_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sha1 | rm |  | rm |
| Sha2 | rw |  | rw |
| Sha3 |  |  | rw |
| Sha4 |  | tr |  |

In particular, the dataset currently contains about 2000 columns.

I want to reduce the number of columns removing as many as possible the empty rows, as follows:

| sha | 0_x | 1_x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sha1 | rm | rm |
| Sha2 | rw | rw |
| Sha3 | rw |  |
| Sha4 | tr |  |

I don't care about the names of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming empty cells are `NaN`, if not, first `replace('', np.nan)`.

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
cols = df.columns[1:]
# ['0_x', '1_x', 'N_x']

(df.set_index('sha')
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .assign(cols=lambda d: d.groupby('sha')
                           .cumcount()
                           .map(dict(enumerate(cols)))
          )
   .pivot(index='sha', columns='cols', values=0)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Other option, with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
cols = list(df.columns[1:])
# ['0_x', '1_x', 'N_x']

(df.set_index('sha')
   .apply(lambda s: s.dropna().reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(cols[:len(d.columns)], axis=1))
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
cols   sha 0_x  1_x
0     Sha1  rm   rm
1     Sha2  rw   rw
2     Sha3  rw  NaN
3     Sha4  tr  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.set_index('sha')
 .replace(r'$', '_', regex=True)
 .replace(np.nan, '')
 .sum(numeric_only=False, axis=1)
 .str.split('_+', regex=True, expand=True)
 .replace('', np.nan)
 .dropna(how='all', axis=1)
 .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.astype('str') + '_x', axis=1))
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
    sha 0_x  1_x
0  Sha1  rm   rm
1  Sha2  rw   rw
2  Sha3  rw  NaN
3  Sha4  tr  NaN
```